# How to set attribute.Metadata field in .callServer with Javascript Var?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, standard-objects, helper, oop

I tried to get the description of the title correct. If you think there might be a better one that describes better the scenario, please suggest!

In lightning components, I have a **cpq_Configure** component. In the helper I have a function that gets the experience attribute. This experience attribute is an array with just 1 item. The **QR_Field__c** is a **metadata field,** which is **equal to a field on the quote object**. For example, there can be multiple experiences, and each experience will have their QR_Field__c field set to a different field on the quote object.

Now what I want to do is stamp **v.experience[0].QR_Field__c** with the value in the attribute **arr**. I am wanting to stamp the quote field that is in this metadata field with the value in arr, which would theoretically be an amount.

[image]

When it comes to calling the server, I'm setting the quote fields directly through **newItem.** For example, setting **newItem.OpportunityId = component.get('v.quoteName');**. *OpportunityId is a field that is on the quote object*. However, **I want to see if there's a way instead of directly calling a field on the quote object to call a var in the javascript function.** For example, qrField's value is 'Quota_Relief_VOC__c' for the particular experience it is (CX) because that's what the value is for it on the metadata record (refer to picture below). 
[image]
Any suggestions on how to pass this through using a javascript var? Or better suggestions on how to accomplish this in general? **Here is the markup so you can get a better grip at this.**

```
createUpgradeQuote : function(component, event, helper){
    console.log('Configure Helper: CreateUpgradeQuote');
    console.log(component.get('v.exp'));

    var exp = component.get('v.exp');
    var arr = component.get('v.arr');

    //Set experience array
    var experiences = component.get('v.experienceMetaData');
    var experience = _.filter(experiences, {'Code__c' : exp});
    component.set('v.experience', experience);

    var qrField = component.get('v.experience[0].QR_Field__c');
    console.log('The qrField value is: ' + qrField);        

    var Quote = component.get('v.quote');
    var bundleName = component.get('v.selectedBundle')[0].Name;
    var serviceQlis = component.get('v.serviceQlis');
    var quoteType = component.get('v.quoteType');
    var templateCodes = '';
    var newItem = {};

    _.forEach(serviceQlis, function(value) {
        if(value.Template_Code__c != null) {
            templateCodes+=value.Template_Code__c + ',';
        }
    });

    //if(quoteType == 'change-dates') {
        //newItem.'qrField' = licenseARR 

    //}

    newItem = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Quote));
    newItem.Name = component.get('v.quoteName');
    newItem.qrField
    newItem.OpportunityId = component.get('v.opportunity.Id');
    newItem.Pricebook2Id = '01s500000001tHMAAY';
    newItem.License_Term_in_months__c = component.get('v.quoteTerm');
    newItem.Quote_Type__c = "New License";
    newItem.License_Length_Input__c = component.get('v.quoteTerm');
    newItem.XM_Products__c = component.get('v.selectedBundle')[0].Name;
    newItem.PostBundleDiscountAmount__c  = component.get('v.netTotal');
    newItem.License_Start_Date__c = component.get('v.quoteStartDate');
    newItem.License_End_Date__c = component.get('v.quoteEndDate');
    newItem.Last_Configuration__c = new Date();
    newItem.Service_Template_Codes__c = templateCodes;
    //quoteEndDate = moment.utc(quoteEndDate).subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    helper.callServer( 
        component,
        "c.saveRecord",
        function(response) {               
            var recordId = response.Id;
            helper.createQuoteLineItem(component,recordId,helper);

        },
        {
            record : newItem,
            startDate : component.get('v.quoteStartDate')
        }
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to this that I was able to find out. If I pass **qrField** over to my Apex method, I am be able to use the put method (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm).

It would look something like this in Apex:

```
@isAuraEnabled
Static void createUpdateQuote(Quote q, String qrField, String myValue){

q.put(qrField, myValue);

}
```